# C# topmost object over video flickers.

Tags: c#, video, topmost

I am facing problems with a desktop application that runs some video player 
and managed with transparency color i'm trying to put over the video some element. 
I have tried with an image, a simple label but it flickers.

This happens just with some old pc. 
Does anybody have idea how can i handle this situation and prevent this ugly effect?

Comment: Are you using WinForms to do this? Are you setting your controls to be DoubleBuffered?

Comment: I am using winforms... and no i never heard about the doublebuffered. i have to try it tomorrow with one of these old pc

Comment: Make sure to set not only the main form doing the drawing's DoubleBuffered property to true, but also the controls responsible for the drawing as well, if just the form doesn't work. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've just set in fact just the controls, but as i said can't test it now... is enough or I have to set it even to the main form?

Comment: I haven't encountered a situation in which DoubleBuffered controls were a bad thing, so I see no harm in setting it for the form as well. If when you test later on you're still having flickering issues, you might want to have a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046560/how-to-stop-flickering-c-sharp-winforms) for some more advanced options.