# How to make my panel stop flickering

Tags: c#, panel, windows-forms-designer

Hi i am trying to make a panel that will show some text when it hovered over a picture and i want it to follow the cursor so i

```
System.Windows.Forms.Panel pan = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Product p = new Product();
        p.SetValues();
        this.pictureBox1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("pictureName");

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pan.Height = 200;
        pan.Width = 100;
        pan.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        this.Controls.Add(pan);
        pan.BringToFront();
        //pan.Location = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls.Remove(pan);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pan.Location = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);  
    }
```

I tried adding `this.doublebuffered = true;`
but it just make it look like there are after image of the panel when i move my mouse

when i hover over my picture it shows the panel but it flickers like crazy 
is this normal or is there a fix for this or this is my computers problem

Comment: I assume that the panels is redrawn everytime you move your mouse. Maybe only use the `MouseHover` event (no `MouseMove`) and set the [MousHoverTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousehovertime(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if that works propertly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop flickering C# winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046560/how-to-stop-flickering-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: oh sorry i change the action from hover to enter 
i was just reusing the code

Comment: I thought so. Do edit the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `this.DoubleDuffered = true;` to the `Form` does only affect the `Form`, not the `Panel`.

So use a doubleBuffered `Panel` **subclass**:

```
class DrawPanel : Panel
{
    public DrawPanel ()
    {
      this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

However moving large things around will take its toll. 
Btw, the `PictureBox` class is already doubleBuffered. Also it seems more logical to add the Panel to the PictureBox, not the Form: `pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pan);` And adding a `pictureBox1.Refresh();` to the `MouseMove`.

**Update**: As you don't draw on the Panel and also need to it to overlap the PictureBox the above ideas do not really apply; using the subclass is not necessary, although it may come handy at some point. And yes, the Panel needs to be added to the Form's Controls collection!

This code works just fine here:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // your other init code here

    Controls.Add(pan);  // add only once
    pan.BringToFront();
    pan.Hide();         // and hide or show
    this.DoubleDuffered = true  // !!
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pan.Hide();         // hide or show
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pan.Location = pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();  // !!
    Refresh();              // !!
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pan.Height = 200;
    pan.Width = 100;
    pan.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    pan.Location = pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    pan.Show();        // and hide or show
}
```

Looks like you were missing the right combination of **doublebuffering** the `Form` and **refreshing** both, the `Form` and the `PictureBox`.

Comment: Nope the panel still flickers when moving the mouse even though it happen less

Comment: Actually I tried your code as it is and see __no__ flicker. How large is the image?

Comment: width is 209 height is 319

Comment: still have flickering even when the mouse does not move but it a huge improvement as it only flicker a few times only

Comment: adding the panel to the picturebox1 does not even show the panel as it is trap within the picturebox1 display area

Comment: apparently using `e.location;` makes it so that it will get the position of the cursor relative to the image the put it at the form so when i hover my cursor at the pictureBox1 position at (0,0) then the panel will appear at (0,0) so in a way i just need to add position of the picturebox to the `e.location` code

Comment: That works if and only if the Panel is nested in the PictureBox. Do you need to let the Panel to overlap the PictureBox? It is larger large for a 209 x319  picturebox!

Comment: yeah i need the panel to be outside of the picture box

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense! I habe modified the answer.. Looks like you were missing the right combination of doublebuffering the form and refreshing both, the form and the picturebox..

Comment: It work perfectly now as i change the line of  `pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);` to `this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)`  and now it wokes the way i wanted it to be Thanks alot for helping me