# quick black panel when click show\hide button

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have an application in C#, and I added one button to show and hide panel2, but when clicked the panel 2 is works perfect to showing and hide itself. but something wrong when click the button show/hide panel2 gives a *quick black things*, i don't know how to fix it.
this is my **show/hide button syntax**:

```
 if (Panel2.Visible == false) {
            Panel2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Panel2.Visible = true;
            PictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.downmen;


        } else {
            Panel2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Panel2.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            PictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.upmen;
        }
```

this is my problem show:
[image]

Comment: Enable double buffering on the form

Comment: @Gusman, what does mean?, please enplane it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop flickering C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046560/how-to-stop-flickering-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: While I've marked this as being a duplicate, if you're not too far into the project, I would recommend looking into using WPF or even UWP instead of winforms for a project this visually complex.

Comment: Try putting calls to `Panel2.SuspendLayout()` and `Panel2.ResumeLayout()` around your code so the panel doesn't repaint part way through updating its properties.

Answer (score 0):

May be too late for the answer. Set the default height and width (size) of Panel2 to 0.
Set size of Panel2 based on the visibility of control