# Reliable method to prevent possible flickering of a Form's back color that should be always invisible?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

When a Form has loaded there is often a short flicker of its back color that shows up at the same time when the form's BackgroundImage goes visible.
Is there any reliable method to actually prevent the flicker itself when the image is showing up, rather than just placing the Form beyond the visible screen area, so that the user can't see the flicker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop flickering C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046560/how-to-stop-flickering-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: The issue I'm experiencing with back color flicker that happens once when the BackgroundImage has loaded is most likely not equal with the flickering issue in that topic. I remember this suggested thread. It's about flickering when drawing graphics elements and I couldn't find a working solution there that adresses my problem.

Comment: I'm was able to change the appearance of the back color popup and how long it stays visible, but I'm not sure what I could do to get rid of it.

Comment: I think I'm after something now...