# how to avoid flickering winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I write a simple program that sends ICMP-requests. The program polls every host in own thread. The problem is flickering table on Form with labels and buttons where are shown results. I try set on Doublebuffered in Form, but it don't help.

```cs
private void pingThreadmain(object number_thread) {            
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();            
    // поток работает, пока установлена глобальная переменная
    while (thread_ping) {                
        // замеряем время запуска пинга
        int start_ping = Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue;
        // получаем таймаут из таблицы
        string timeout = "";
        Action action_timeout = () => timeout = list_timeout[(int)number_thread].Text;
        list_timeout[(int)number_thread].Invoke(action_timeout);
        // пингуем хост
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(list_ip[(int)number_thread].Text, Int32.Parse(timeout));
        // вычисляем время выполнения пинга
        int duration_ping = Int32.Parse(timeout) - (Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue) + start_ping;
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
            // если хост отвечает
            // изменяем визуальные компоненты
            Action action_status = () => list_status[(int)number_thread].BackColor = Color.Green;
            list_status[(int)number_thread].Invoke(action_status);
            Action action_rtt = () => list_rtt[(int)number_thread].Text = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
            list_rtt[(int)number_thread].Invoke(action_rtt);
            // проверяем что таймаут паузы не отрицательный
            if (duration_ping > 0) {
                Thread.Sleep(duration_ping);
            }
        }
        else {
            // если хост не отвечает
            // изменяем визуальные компоненты 
            Action action_status = () => list_status[(int)number_thread].BackColor = Color.Red;
            list_status[(int)number_thread].Invoke(action_status);
            Action action_rtt = () => list_rtt[(int)number_thread].Text = "---";
            list_rtt[(int)number_thread].Invoke(action_rtt);
            Action action_fail = () => list_fail[(int)number_thread].Text = (Int32.Parse(list_fail[(int)number_thread].Text) + 1).ToString();
            list_fail[(int)number_thread].Invoke(action_fail);
            // выводим сообщение о недоступности хоста
            AddLog($"нет ответа от {list_ip[(int)number_thread].Text} {list_name[(int)number_thread].Text}");
            // проверяем что таймаут паузы не отрицательный
            if (duration_ping > 0) {
                Thread.Sleep(duration_ping);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `thread_ping` is `volatile`? if not, throw out your code completely.

Comment: You need to enable double buffering not for the form, but for the controls that are output to.

Answer (score 0):

The line `this.DoubleBuffered = true` should have worked.

It seems that it is  not in the `YourProject.YourProject` class

> It should be in the class so that the double buffering can be correctly implemented.

You should also try `ControlStyles Enum` [ControlStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles?view=netcore-3.1) . It should be implemented under SetStyle, which must be of the type `YourProject.YourProject`.

You can find additional ways here - [how to stop flickering C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046560/how-to-stop-flickering-c-sharp-winforms).